# jquery plugins and closures

Tags: jquery, closures

I am making a form validation function and have the following code for it

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.validate_thing = function (success_call_back) {
        var call_back = true;
        debugger;
        if (!this.is('form')) {
            return false;
        }

        $('input.empty').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).text()) {
                alert($(this).attr('name'));
                call_back = false;
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that when the page loads I get a javascript error saying that 'object is not a function' on the (jQuery) line. If I step through this with the debugger I don't get this problem. If I put this in a document ready function I don't get this problem. I'm thinking that it might have something to do with jQuery not being loaded with this script is run, but I include the jQuery library before the library that contains this code, not to mention if I don't do this in a closure, i.e. do this

```
$.fn.validate_thing = function (success_call_back) {
    var call_back = true;
    debugger;
    if (!this.is('form')) {
        return false;
    }

    $('input.empty').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).text()) {
            alert($(this).attr('name'));
            call_back = false;
        }
    });
}
```

it works.

So I have a few work arounds for this problem but I'd still like to know why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

here's what i have before it in the javascript page

```
engine = new function() {
this.request = function ( params ) {
    var data = params.data ? params.data : '';

    if (params.url) {
        var url = params.url;
        var page = document.URL.split('/').pop();
        var page = page.split('.')[0];
        data += 'content_page='+page+'.tpl';
    }
    else {
        var url = document.URL;
    }

    debugger;
    if (params.action) {
        data += data ? '&action='+params.action : "action="+params.action;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : 'POST',
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            debugger;
            if (data && data.partials) {
                for (var key in data.partials) {
                    var element = data.partials[key];
                    $('#'+element.partial_name).replaceWith(element.partial_content);
                }
            }
        },
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;

            alert('ajax error: '+errorThrown);
        }
    }).success(params.success);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other code before that part? If you get an error in the last line, it might interpret the parenthesis `( function() { ... } )` as function call of whatever precedes the code (I admit, it's a long shot).

Comment: `(function($){})(jQuery);` immediately executes a function, passing in the `jQuery` object (which will be `$` inside the function). For what you are doing, I think that enclosure is not necessary

Comment: @MrOBrian: It is common practice to do this when defining jQuery plugins. The global `$` might not refer to jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling True, and I have all my plugins wrapped that way with no problems, but since he mentioned it works without the wrapping, I was just offering that it didn't seem necessary to use it in this case

Comment: @MrOBrian I could leave it out but I am interested in why this is happening and not how to fix it, as I already have a couple of work arounds, but thanks for the advise.

Comment: @FelixKling Your a genius and i'm a goof lol. I put the code at the beginning of the file and it fixed it, which was weird. I then realized I missed the semi colon at the end of the function that previously preceded it. Thanks for the help you guys! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome :) I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an error in the last line, it is likely that JavaScript interprets the parenthesis `( function() { ... } )` as function call of whatever precedes the code. This can happen if you forgot a semicolon in the previous line.

Consider this:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = foo
(function() {

}());
```

Note that the semicolon is missing after `foo` and therefore JavaScript interprets the code as `foo(...)`, which throws the error

> object is not a function